# Getting duplicates after list comprehension

Tags: python

I have two lists of dictionaries such as:

```
l1 = [{"ticket_type": "A1", "ticket_count": 30, "ticket_price": 1000.0},
      {"ticket_type": "A2", "ticket_count": 70, "ticket_price": 500.0},
      {"ticket_type": "A3", "ticket_count": 5, "ticket_price": 1200.0}]

l2 = [{"ticket_type": "A2", "ticket_booked": 2},
      {"ticket_type": "A1", "ticket_booked": 2},
      {"ticket_type": "A3", "ticket_booked": 2}]
```

If the key `ticket_type` in both l1 and l2 match, then subtract corresponding `ticket_booked` in l2 from `ticket_count` in l1. The desired output is:

```
[{'ticket_type': 'A1', 'ticket_count': 28, 'ticket_price': 1000.0}, 
 {'ticket_type': 'A2', 'ticket_count': 68, 'ticket_price': 500.0}, 
 {'ticket_type': 'A3', 'ticket_count': 3, 'ticket_price': 1200.0}]
```

This is what I have tried:

```
for x in l1:
    for y in l2:
        if x["ticket_type"] == y["ticket_type"]:
            x["ticket_count"] -= y["ticket_booked"]
```

I am trying to optimize this method using list comprehension such as:

```
[{**x, **{"ticket_count": x["ticket_count"] - y["ticket_booked"]}} if x["ticket_type"] == y["ticket_type"] else x for x in l1 for y in l2]
```

But I am getting duplicate entries in the final result:

```
[{'ticket_type': 'A1', 'ticket_count': 30, 'ticket_price': 1000.0}, 
 {'ticket_type': 'A1', 'ticket_count': 28, 'ticket_price': 1000.0}, 
 {'ticket_type': 'A1', 'ticket_count': 30, 'ticket_price': 1000.0}, 
 {'ticket_type': 'A2', 'ticket_count': 68, 'ticket_price': 500.0}, 
 {'ticket_type': 'A2', 'ticket_count': 70, 'ticket_price': 500.0}, 
 {'ticket_type': 'A2', 'ticket_count': 70, 'ticket_price': 500.0}, 
 {'ticket_type': 'A3', 'ticket_count': 5, 'ticket_price': 1200.0}, 
 {'ticket_type': 'A3', 'ticket_count': 5, 'ticket_price': 1200.0}, 
 {'ticket_type': 'A3', 'ticket_count': 3, 'ticket_price': 1200.0}]
```

Comment: List comprehensions do not "optimize" anything. They desugar to literally `for` loops and are no more efficient. All it does is make your code shorter (and, in this case, significantly harder to read)

Answer (score 4):

If `ticket_type` is a unique key in `l1`, you may want to make this a dictionary. By doing this lookups based on `ticket_type` are optimized.

```
d1 = {x['ticket_type']: x for x in l1}
# {'A1': {'ticket_type': 'A1', 'ticket_count': 30, 'ticket_price': 1000.0}, 
#  'A2': {'ticket_type': 'A2', 'ticket_count': 70, 'ticket_price': 500.0}, 
#  'A3': {'ticket_type': 'A3', 'ticket_count': 5, 'ticket_price': 1200.0}}
```

Now we loop over `l2` and can efficiently subtract tickets from `d1`.

```
for x in l2:
  if x['ticket_type'] in d1:
    d1[x['ticket_type']]['ticket_count'] -= x['tickets_booked']
```

The value of `d1`:

```
{'A1': {'ticket_type': 'A1', 'ticket_count': 28, 'ticket_price': 1000.0}, 
 'A2': {'ticket_type': 'A2', 'ticket_count': 68, 'ticket_price': 500.0}, 
 'A3': {'ticket_type': 'A3', 'ticket_count': 3, 'ticket_price': 1200.0}}
```

And if you just want the list of dictionaries:

```
>>> list(d1.values())
# [{'ticket_type': 'A1', 'ticket_count': 28, 'ticket_price': 1000.0}, 
#  {'ticket_type': 'A2', 'ticket_count': 68, 'ticket_price': 500.0},
#  {'ticket_type': 'A3', 'ticket_count': 3, 'ticket_price': 1200.0}]
```

Answer (score 3):

What is slow in your approach is reading again `l2` for each step in the loop.

You can optimize your code using a dictionary of ticket_type: ticket_count in place of `l2`:

```
d2 = {d['ticket_type']: d['ticket_booked'] for d in l2}
# {'A2': 2, 'A1': 2, 'A3': 2}

for d in l1:
    d['ticket_count'] -= d2.get(d['ticket_type'], 0)
```

Output:

```
[{'ticket_type': 'A1', 'ticket_count': 28, 'ticket_price': 1000.0},
 {'ticket_type': 'A2', 'ticket_count': 68, 'ticket_price': 500.0},
 {'ticket_type': 'A3', 'ticket_count': 3, 'ticket_price': 1200.0}]
```

Assuming `N` the length of `l1` and `M` that of `l2`, your code had a complexity of `O(N*M)`. The dictionary approach has a complexity of `O(N+M)`.

If you can have several dictionaries with the same `ticket_type` in `l2`, you first need to aggregate the booked counts:

```
from collections import Counter

d2 = Counter()
for d in l2:
    d2[d['ticket_type']] += d['ticket_booked']
# Counter({'A2': 2, 'A1': 2, 'A3': 2})

for d in l1:
    d['ticket_count'] -= d2.get(d['ticket_type'], 0)
```